# How to reset the stack navigator and then navigate to a Tab in Tab navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

## My code looks like this

```
onPress={() => {
  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: "Tab1",
    actions: [navigation.navigate({ routeName: "Tab1" })]
  });

  navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}}
```

I want to navigate to Tab1 from 2nd screen of my stack navigator by resetting the stack. I am not using Redux for this. In a current way, I am either able to reset the stack or move to the Tab1 page(it is being added as a separate screen on the stack). 
I would like to do reset the stack first and then move on to the Tab1 screen. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my success example

The code will open two screens and judge which screen to display in front based on `index`, `index` 0 : display the first one, `index` 1 : display the second one (the `tab1` screen will be displayed here)

Hopefully it helped you

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'home' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Tab1' })
  ]
})

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the information. But I get an error saying NavigationActions.reset is not a function. Could you please help me with that.. @Bin Feng. I am using StackActions.reset and it only navigates to The Tab1 screen but does not reset my stack.